# How to access $_POST variables with unknown keys in a safe way?

Tags: php

My php file receives $_POST variables with unknown numbered keys, e.g. the textpart of the keys is known, but the numbers and amount of $_POST variables are unknown. Example: $_POST[name1], $_POST[name2], $_POST[address1],$_POST[address2].

The only way I see to access these values is by means of some code like below:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
  if(strpos($k, 'name') === 0) {
    //do something with $v
  }
  if(strpos($k, 'address') === 0) {
    //do something with $v
  }

}
```

However, my Netbeans then produces a warning 'Do not access superglobal $_POST array directly'. I looked at php filter input functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) but could not find a way to access these type of $_POST variables in a safe way. Any suggestions? And for starters (question as a beginner:), why is it unsafe practise to access $_POST vars directly?

Comment: Maybe assign `$_POST` to some `$temp_array` and do a `foreach` on that then?

Comment: @techouse I dont see any sense in that practice.

Comment: Was a stupid idea :D Basically just thinking out loud :D

Comment: I believe that using global arrays is discouraged because of possibility of changing the data. Assigning eg. $_POST to other variable mitigates that risk, so it's not senseless in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When working with a variable number of keys as input, you could format your html so that it looks like:

```
<input type="text" name="multi_values[1]" />
<input type="text" name="multi_values[2]" />
```

Now you can access those variables like this:

```
foreach($_POST['multi_values'] as $k => $v){
  //do something with $k and $v
}
```

Furthermore I can think of 2 reasons why NetBeans may throw such a warning: superglobals could be mutated while iterating over them (at least in languages that support concurrency) and the content of the `$_POST` variable is unstable/potentially malicious because it's controlled by the request of the user/browser. That said, in PHP you are allowed to loop over the `$_POST` array just fine. Just always check and sanitize the input.

Comment: And you can take this even a step further: `<input ... name="entry[0][name]"/><input ... name="entry[0][address]"/><input ... name="entry[1][name]"/>...`

Comment: thnx for your comment. Sorry, I know how to access $_POST vars with unknown keys (see my updated text above), but my question was actually how to do this in a SAFE way. As mentioned, according to Netbeans one should not access $_POST vars directly, but by means of some filter function...

Comment: In a safe way: check if the keys in the post array match the keys you want to process exactly, then sanitize the input (e.g strip unwanted slashes, quotes and html input). A lot of evil stuff can be done by potential attackers if you do not sanitize input.

Comment: that means you still access $_POST by means of a for each loop like in your or my example (?) - with the resulting warning of Netbeans...

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. Unless you use multi-threading in your PHP application plus some other weird stuff, which I highly doubt. NetBeans just warns you about the potential risk of looping over the unknown.

Answer (score 0):

**You can access $_POST variable in safe way**
like:

$name = strip_tags( trim( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) );

$pageID = (int) $_POST[ 'page_ID' ];

**Checking the length of variables**

if ( strlen( $_POST[ 'comment' ] ) <= 256 )

$comment = htmlentities ( trim ( $_POST[ 'comment' ] ) , ENT_NOQUOTES );